In which order are disks listed in Windows Task Manager?
Example:

In which order are disks listed in Windows Task Manager? I couldn't see any pattern. (e.g., not based on alphabetical order on partition letter)

Do they correspond to the order of the drives in Disk Management? Also, is there an underlying problem you're trying to solve?

Some suggest the order is based on the order of the ports on the mainboard the drives are connected to: https://linustechtips.com/topic/1166861-drive-order-in-task-manager/ Others suggest it is based on the order which Plug and Play enumerates the drives: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/disk-drive-numbers-may-not-correspond-to-the-sata-channel-numbers-when-you-install-windows-on-a-computer-that-has-multiple-sata-or-raid-disks-864bae20-e7dd-6b4e-7cdd-359be0a6d546

As two of your disks in question are USB, what happens when you disconnect them and reconnect them in different orders, or when you connect them prior to OS boot?

Disk Management or disk part what are the disk numbers for each drive?

On a machine of mine with 4 volumes, the order in Task Manager is the same as the ascending order of the drive Number shown in the output of the Get-Disk PowerShell cmdlet, which is also the same as the port numbers from the adapter interfaces as seen in the PhysicalLocation column of Get-PhysicalDisk (bus, device, function, adapter, port). A Storage Space volume appears at the end, which is also where its last constituent disk number appears.

This question should include more details and clarify the problem.
